# Case insensitive phone name lookup containing cyrillics on Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm trying to get list of contacts using this simple query, which works perfectly ignorig case of input filter until i try to search names containing cyrillics:

```
Cursor c = this.getContext().getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PHONE_PROJECTION, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"+filter+"%'", null,     Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED + " DESC");
```

The problem is this piece of code returns names containing cyrillics only for exact match - so it is case sensitive for cyrillics. I'd like to have the search to be case insensitive for cyrillics too. App runs on min SDK 2.1

The system itself (tested on 4.0 ICS) is capable of doing case insensitive search in contact list (default system app - People).

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code,
Make sure to handle the rest i made an example
This is the fixed code:

```
 String name = "contact_name_to_search_for"
 Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,"DISPLAY_NAME" + " LIKE '%"+name+"%'", null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED + " DESC");
```

This is the full handled code i made for example

```
String name = "contact_name_to_search_for"
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,"DISPLAY_NAME" + " LIKE '%"+name+"%'", null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED + " DESC");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)).toLowerCase();
        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId.toLowerCase(), null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            switch (type) {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Home number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Work number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    cursor.close();
```